# Spring web MVC Hibernate File upload error

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-mvc

I am making a spring project where I am trying to upload an image

editProfile.jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <form:form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/editprofilehandler" method="POST" modelAttribute="userForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        First Name :
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <form:input path="firstName" value="${userDetails[0].firstName }" /> <form:errors path="firstName" class="error" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Last Name :
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <form:input path="lastName" value="${userDetails[0].lastName }" /> <form:errors path="lastName" class="error" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>    
                    <td>
                        EmailID Name :
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <form:input path="emailID" value="${userDetails[0].emailID }" /> <form:errors path="emailID" class="error" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                         Mobile No :
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <form:input path="mobileNo" value="${userDetails[0].mobileNo }" /> <form:errors path="mobileNo" class="error" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>    
                    <td>
                        Date of birth :
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <form:input path="dateOfBirth" value="${userDetails[0].dateOfBirth }" /> <form:errors path="dateOfBirth" class="error" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Gender :
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <form:input path="gender" value="${userDetails[0].gender }" /> <form:errors path="gender" class="error" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Profile image :
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="file" name="uploadImage" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" colspan="2">
                        <input type="submit" value="Update" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            </form:form>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Controllerr.java

```
@SuppressWarnings("resource")
    @RequestMapping("/editprofilehandler")
    public ModelAndView editProfileHandlerController(@ModelAttribute("userForm") Users users , ModelMap model, HttpSession session)
    {       
        if(session.getAttribute("session_user") != null){
            try
            {
                InputStream inputStream = null;
                OutputStream outputStream = null;
                MultipartFile file = users.getImage();
                String fileName = file.getOriginalFilename();
                inputStream = file.getInputStream();

                File newFile = new File("C:/Documents and Settings/smart/workspace/Pir/WebContent/resources/images/profile/" + fileName);
                if(!newFile.exists())
                {

                }
                outputStream = new FileOutputStream(newFile);
                int read = 0;
                byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

                while((read = inputStream.read(bytes)) != -1)
                    outputStream.write(bytes, 0, read);

            }
            catch(Exception e){}
            List<Object[]> userDetails = this.userFunctionsService.getUserDetails(((UserLoginDetails)session.getAttribute("session_user")).getEmailID());
            model.addAttribute("userDetails", userDetails);
            return new ModelAndView("editProfile", model);
        }
        else
            return new ModelAndView("redirect:/");
    }
```

Users.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class Users {

    @NotNull
    @Id
    @Column(name = "userID")
    private int userID;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min=3, max=50)
    @Pattern(regexp = ".+@.+\\.[a-z]+")
    @Column(name = "emailID")
    private String emailID;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min=3, max=50)
    @Column(name = "firstName")
    private String firstName;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min=3, max=50)
    @Column(name = "lastName")
    private String lastName;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min=3, max=50)
    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "mobileNo")
    private String mobileNo;


    @Column(name = "imageURL")
    private String imageURL;

    @NotNull
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern="MM/dd/yyyy")
    @Column(name = "dateOfBirth")
    private Date dateOfBirth;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "gender")
    private String gender;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "userType")
    private String userType;

    @Lob
    private MultipartFile image;

    public void setUserID(int userID)
    {
        this.userID = userID;
    }
    public int getUserID()
    {
        return userID;
    }
    public void setEmailID(String emailID)
    {
        this.emailID = emailID;
    }
    public String getEmailID()
    {
        return emailID;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName)
    {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public String getFirstName()
    {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName)
    {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    public String getLastName()
    {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password)
    {
        this.password = password;
    }
    public String getPassword()
    {
        return password;
    }
    public void setMobileNo(String mobileNo)
    {
        this.mobileNo = mobileNo;
    }
    public String getMobileNo()
    {
        return mobileNo;
    }
    public void setImageURL(String imageURL)
    {
        this.imageURL = imageURL;
    }
    public String getImageURL()
    {
        return imageURL;
    }
    public void setDateOfBirth(Date dateOfBirth)
    {
        this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
    }
    public Date getDateOfBirth()
    {
        return dateOfBirth;
    }
    public void setGender(String gender)
    {
        this.gender = gender;
    }
    public String getGender()
    {
        return gender;
    }
    public void setUsetType(String userType)
    {
        this.userType = userType;
    }
    public String getUserType()
    {
        return userType;
    }
    public void setImage(MultipartFile image)
    {
        this.image = image;
    }
    public MultipartFile getImage()
    {
        return image;
    }

}
```

Error:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "imageURL"
    java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:492)
    java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
    javax.el.ArrayELResolver.coerce(ArrayELResolver.java:166)
    javax.el.ArrayELResolver.getValue(ArrayELResolver.java:46)
    org.apache.jasper.el.JasperELResolver.getValue(JasperELResolver.java:104)
    org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:183)
    org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:185)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.proprietaryEvaluate(PageContextImpl.java:1026)
    org.apache.jsp.view.profile_jsp._jspService(profile_jsp.java:78)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:954)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doInclude(PageContextImpl.java:684)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.include(PageContextImpl.java:678)
    org.apache.tiles.request.jsp.JspRequest.doInclude(JspRequest.java:123)
    org.apache.tiles.request.AbstractViewRequest.dispatch(AbstractViewRequest.java:47)
    org.apache.tiles.request.render.DispatchRenderer.render(DispatchRenderer.java:47)
    org.apache.tiles.request.render.ChainedDelegateRenderer.render(ChainedDelegateRenderer.java:68)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:259)
    org.apache.tiles.template.InsertAttributeModel.renderAttribute(InsertAttributeModel.java:188)
    org.apache.tiles.template.InsertAttributeModel.execute(InsertAttributeModel.java:132)
    org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.doTag(InsertAttributeTag.java:299)
    org.apache.jsp.template.mainTemplate_jsp._jspx_meth_tiles_005finsertAttribute_005f2(mainTemplate_jsp.java:340)
    org.apache.jsp.template.mainTemplate_jsp._jspService(mainTemplate_jsp.java:130)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.tiles.request.servlet.ServletRequest.forward(ServletRequest.java:265)
    org.apache.tiles.request.servlet.ServletRequest.doForward(ServletRequest.java:228)
    org.apache.tiles.request.AbstractClientRequest.dispatch(AbstractClientRequest.java:57)
    org.apache.tiles.request.render.DispatchRenderer.render(DispatchRenderer.java:47)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:259)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:397)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:238)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:221)
    org.apache.tiles.renderer.DefinitionRenderer.render(DefinitionRenderer.java:59)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView.renderMergedOutputModel(TilesView.java:132)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1244)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1027)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:971)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:858)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

`imageURL` column is varchar in mysql. How to solve this error?

EDIT

profile.jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td valign="top">
            <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath }/changeimage">
                <img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath }/resources/images/profile/${userDetails[0].imageURL }" height="145" width="200" />
            </a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        First Name :
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <c:out value="${userDetails[0].firstName }" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Last Name :
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <c:out value="${userDetails[0].lastName }" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>    
                    <td>
                        EmailID Name :
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <c:out value="${userDetails[0].emailID }" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                         Mobile No :
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <c:out value="${userDetails[0].mobileNo }" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>    
                    <td>
                        Date of birth :
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <c:out value="${userDetails[0].dateOfBirth }" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>    
                    <td>
                        Gender :
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <c:out value="${userDetails[0].gender }" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>            
        </td>
        <td align="right" valign="top">
            <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath }/editprofile">Edit</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: we need to see profile.jsp

Comment: you are getting this error on Jsp Page , if so please share that page code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a loop which transforms the `List<Object[]>` into a `List<User>` before placing the list into the model in **Controllerr.java**.

Or you should change the code

which would return a `List<User>` instead of a `List<Object[]>`.

Hope This will resolve the issue